# Bootstrap max 2 col div next to eachother

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I want is this. When there's only 1 `div`, it should be 100% width. When I add a `div`, both div's must be 50% and floating next to eachother.
Is this possible with bootstrap, something with the `col-md-6` and `col-md-12` classes?

Comment: I think you should consider using a scripted action, eg. jQuery, or let some server-sided script hussle.

Comment: @Adimeus, I think so too, but I'm wondering if it is possible with just bootstrap classes

Comment: How are you planning to add the second div?

Comment: @ArshadMuhammed Problem is already solved using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the relevant classes serverside or with javascript on clientside. It is not possible to have this with the same html/css.

The desired html source for your cases are:

*First*

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">Your content</div>
</div>
```

*Second*

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Your content</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Your content</div>
</div>
```